# Multivariate Gaussian decomposition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I've seen around the claim that an $n$-dimensional Gaussian random variable (say, having unit covariance) can be decomposed into the product of two independent random variables.
$$U=ZS$$
where $Z$ is a scalar representing the distance from the origin, and $S$ is an $n$-dimensional direction distributed uniformally over the unit sphere.

How can this be proven?

Comment: Just write your random variable $x$ as $x = \|x\| \cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|}$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $l^2$-norm/distance from origin.

Comment: @Michael this calls for further details, since it needs to be shown the two variables are independent, and there is the issue of deriving the Jacobian when dealing with products of continuous variables.

Comment: Independence is obvious. You have two random variables on a product measure space $[0, \infty) \times S^1$, where the measure on $[0, \infty)$ is given by square root of the $\chi^2_n$ distribution, and the measure on the unit sphere $S^1$ has the uniform distribution. The two random variables in question are projection maps, therefore independent.

Answer (score 0):

The square of your random variable $Z$ of course is distributed as $\chi^2_n$.

The multvariate normal density $N_n(\mathbf 0, I_n)$ is $z\in\mathbb R^n\mapsto\text{constant}\cdot \exp(-\|z\|^2/2)$.  This can be factored as one factor that depends on $z$ only through $\|z\|$ and another that depends on $z$ only through $z/\|z\|$ (the latter factor in this case is $1$).  From that it follows that $\|Z\|$ and $Z/\|Z\|$ are independent.

Comment: There are still missing details to convince me. Could you show that the density of the product of Z (a scalar) and S (vector uniformly distributed on the unit sphere) indeed results in U?

Comment: See for example here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution, where the product distribution is not simply the multiplication of the independent densities. There is another factor which you haven't accounted for and I'm not sure how it looks for this multivariate case

Comment: @Leo : I've shown what you're asking for.  One factor is $\exp(\|z\|^2/2)$ and the other is constant.

Comment: There is no explicit derivation of the distribution of the product (calculation of the integral). As I've pointed out, it does not equal to the multiplication of densities. Moreover, there must be a mistake since $Z$ should be the Rayleigh distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

Comment: I've changed it to say the _square_ of the random variable involved has a chi-square distribution; I'd overlooked that.  You seem confused about the "other factor".  That is something that appears in expressions in which one variable is to get integrated out.  I may write a more leisurely answer here at some point.

Comment: When dealing with a product of random variables, there is indeed an integration involved. Your current answer does not mention anything about your proof technique or why\what it proves. If you mean to express the $f(u)$ as a product of $f(z)$ and $f(s)$, and from this claim $U=ZS$, then it is misleading and wrong. One way to see this is to note Rayleigh density is of the form $f(x;\sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2} e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}, \quad x \geq 0$, which is nowhere to be seen in your decomposition.

Comment: The need to find an integral in the situation considered in the Wikipedia article arises from the fact that values of the product random variable can be factored in more than one way: If $XY=6$, then one could have $X=2$ and $Y=3$, or one could have $X=6$ and $Y=1$, etc.  But in the situation considered here, there is only one way to factor a vector as a point on the unit sphere times a scalar.